# SQL Query to find whether an element was attached within 'X' days from today

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

When I attach an element VTP to an employee the start_date and end_date of per_vtp_table gets affected and pay periods start date and end date gets entered.
Now i want to find whether the VTP element has been created within 15 days from today. For this i have created a query :-

```
Select employee_no,
start_date,
end_date
from 
peR_people pp,
per_vtp_table pvt
where pvt.person_id=pp.person_id
and pvt.start_date between trunc(sysdate)and trunc(sysdate)-15
```

But by this query for example the following data exists

```
per_vtp_table
-------------
start_date   end_date      person_id    Element
12-Oct-2014  28-Oct-2014    1            Vtp
01-Nov-2014  15-nov-2014    1             --

per_people
----------
person_id employee_no
1          67
```

Now 15 days from today I have to check whether VTP Element was created or not. I was attached with the employee on 15-Oct-2014 but the pvt.start_date is 12-NOV-2014
which is why the query I have made is not taking it. Kindly help.. so as to how I can make a full proof query for this requirement.

will this condition be correct ?

```
and trunc(sysdate)-15 between pvt.start_date and pvt.end_date
```

Also I need that if i pass any date explicitly that the details of the employees should be fetched after that date. how can i go with that ? the following query is not working:

```
Select employee_no,
start_date,
end_date
from 
peR_people pp,
per_vtp_table pvt
where pvt.person_id=pp.person_id
and pvt.start_date >:p_resend_date;

per_vtp_table
-------------
start_date   end_date      person_id    Element
12-Oct-2014  28-Oct-2014    1            Vtp
01-Nov-2014  15-nov-2014    1             --
```

Now if i pass the resend date as 27-oct-2014 the 1st row should come up as VTP was attached for person_id 1 on 27-oct-2014 but it is not appearing

Comment: A column in per_vtp table (element) which will have a value if attached iwth the employee

Comment: @user3809240 Can you exactly tell what is your input data and what you want to see as output?

Comment: Can you not do a CRON job (every day) to create the VTP element 15 days later and check wheter `Now 15 days from today I have to check whether VTP Element was created or not.`

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> WITH
  2  per_vtp_table AS(
  3    SELECT TO_DATE('12-Oct-2014', 'dd-mon-yyyy') start_date,
  4           TO_DATE('28-Oct-2014', 'dd-mon-yyyy') end_date,
  5           1 person_id, 'Vtp' ELEMENT FROM dual UNION ALL
  6    SELECT TO_DATE('01-Nov-2014', 'dd-mon-yyyy') start_date,
  7           TO_DATE('15-nov-2014', 'dd-mon-yyyy') end_date,
  8           1 person_id, NULL ELEMENT FROM dual),
  9  per_people AS(
 10    SELECT 1 person_id, 67 employee_no FROM dual)
 11    SELECT 'VTP was attached for person_id'
 12    || pp.person_id
 13    ||' on '
 14    || start_date msg,
 15    employee_no,
 16    start_date,
 17    end_date
 18  FROM peR_people pp,
 19    per_vtp_table pvt
 20  WHERE pvt.person_id=pp.person_id
 21  AND pvt.start_date < to_date('27-Oct-2014', 'dd-mon-yyyy')
 22  /

MSG                                                   EMPLOYEE_NO START_DAT END_DATE
-------------------------------------------- -------------------- --------- ---------
VTP was attached for person_id1 on 12-OCT-14                   67 12-OCT-14 28-OCT-14

SQL>
```